# Why are JodaTime timestamps not re-initializing in Squeryl?

Tags: scala, jodatime, squeryl

Using Scala, JodaTime, and Squeryl for ORM. There's an annoying problem where once the application starts up, a Timestamp generated using JodaTime doesn't re-initialize every time it's called. Instead it sets the time once and annoyingly doesn't re-initialize every time the SQL is called.

Code below. First, the time parameter:

```
val todayEnd = new Timestamp(new DateMidnight(now,  DateTimeZone.forID("America/Los_Angeles")).plusDays(1).getMillis())
```

And the Squeryl JOIN:

```
join(DB.jobs, DB.clients.leftOuter, DB.projects.leftOuter)((j,c,p) =>
        where((j.teamId === teamId)
          and (j.startTime < todayEnd)
          and (j.userId isNotNull)
          and (j.canceled === false)
          and (j.completed === false))
        select(j,c,p)
        on(j.clientId === c.map(_.id), j.projectId === p.map(_.id)))
```

The strange part is that if I generate the `todayEnd` timestamp *without* JodaTime, then it re-initializes every time. So what is JodaTime doing differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem: apparently the thread managing the JOIN was never successfully being shutdown, and was being re-referenced inside Akka. This meant that the `todayEnd` variable had never been re-initialized.

So the take-home lesson is: manage your threads.

### Update

As I have further learned, the original object holding the time values were set as `val`. As it turns out, they need to be `def`.

Bad:

```
val today = new Date()
lazy val today = new Date()
```

Good:

```
def today = new Date()
```